# Changing (function($) {})(jQuery) to an ajaxComplete

Tags: jquery

What would be the appropriate way to changing a function that looks like this:

```
(function($) {})(jQuery);
```

To  using `.ajaxComplete()` with it?

For example i know that I can use:

```
jQuery(document).ajaxComplete(function(){});
```

but is there a way to do it with the `(function($)`?

**--- EDIT ---**

I am sorry, I am relatively new to this sort of thing. I didn't write this thinking that I was so far off to get an uproar for the SO community. Let me try and word my question a bit better...

I have a function that looks like this:

```
(function($) {

    // Some code goes here
})(jQuery);
```

From what understand this is just short had for a `$(document).ready(function(){});`

I would to kick my code off with an `.ajaxComplete()` instead of `.ready()`. Is there an identical way to do this? Or I guess the better question would be is it possible to also pass the IIFE `$` in instead of having to use `jQuery` like the other function currently does?

Comment: That makes no sense.  Why don't you explain what you're trying to do, rather than how you think you should do it.

Comment: Are you aware what does mean: `(function($) {})(jQuery);` ???

Comment: @A.Wolff - I am relatively new to the using javascript/jQuery and didn't think that i would cause that much of an outrage. From what i understand it is just a shorthand for writing `$(document).ready(function(){});`.

Comment: @scapegoat17 It is not, it is not the shorthand `$(handler);` or `$(function(){...})` for ready pseudo event. It's an IIFE passing jQuery as variable. See e.g: http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/   Anyway, your question is unclear imho so improve it by telling us what are you looking for

Comment: @A.Wolff - Sorry, I did not realize. Please see my update

Comment: Following your edit, you could just use: `jQuery(document).ajaxComplete(function(){var $ = jQuery; // Some code goes here});` but is it really what you are looking for?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
(function($) {
   // you can use $ safely here without any conflict issues.
   $(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
     ...
   });
})(jQuery);
```

It is an [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/), which has `$` as its parameter and is passed `jQuery`, so it can be used without any conflicts with any other `$` declared in other libraries.

Comment: I did not down vote, but I guess it's the OP did not express what he want clearly that no answers are good.

Comment: @AmitJoki Not sure regarding downvote but it should be: `$( document ).ajaxComplete(handler);`